# Resolve NetBIOS name on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, protocols, netbios

According to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870913(v=VS.85).aspx), NetBIOS is no longer supported starting from Windwos Vista.  Sure enough, I can no longer see any NetBIOS name from the network properties.

However, when I am writing codes on my Windows 7, I still encounter NetBIOS names in many places. For example

1. I can still use "MYDOMAIN\Harvey" to logon my machine, where I believe MYDOMAIN is a NetBIOS name.
2. The environment variables COMPUTERNAME and USERDOMAIN are still NetBIOS names.  I am expecting to see a DNS names here
3. My SQL Server instance names coming up from my SQL Server Management Studio is still something like MYMACHINE\Instance1.

I am guessing Microsoft still maintains some pieces of it for backward compatibility.  I want to understand how Windows 7 going to resolve the NetBIOS name to an IP address.  I found this article explaining how the [NetBIOS name resolution](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5034239.html) works but I am afraid this is no longer true in Windows 7.  At least there is no WINS server for me.

My last question is how do I do the NetBIOS name resolution programmatically, preferrably in C#.  I am okay to use PInvoke.

***UDAPTE***

Tridus was right.  I can use System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("hostname") to resolve NetBIOS name.  I used reflector to see what's happening under the hood.  It is calling [gethostbyname() from ws2_32.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc758517(WS.10).aspx), it explains the gethostbyname() will do NetBIOS name resolution.

> 1. Check the local host name for a matching name.
> 2. Check the Hosts file for a matching name entry.
> 3. If a DNS server is configured, query it.
> 4. If no match is found, attempt NetBIOS name-resolution.

About the mystery of NetBIOS not supported in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870903(v=VS.85).aspx), I think it just means the API is not supported.  [People in ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/224821/is-netbios-really-gone-on-windows) think that NetBIOS is still supported in Windows 7.

Comment: I suspect you may get more traction on this if it were on ServerFault.

Comment: @bryanbcook Bearing in mind the last line, I suspect that might not be the case. :-)

Comment: @Harvey Kwok - So your goal is to determine the IP address of a computer on the local network based on its computer name?

Comment: Named pipes use netbios names too. They are present both in Windows API and .NET library.

Comment: @Justin Yes, I was trying to find a way to resolve the NetBIOS name to IP address on Windows 7 and then found that the NetBIOS is no longer supported on Windows 7

Comment: @btyanbcook Thanks, I think I should really ask similar question on ServerFault.

Comment: Posted another question on ServerFault http://serverfault.com/questions/224821/is-netbios-really-gone-on-windows.  I renamed this questions title to make it more programmer-related.  I don't want this question to be closed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NetBIOS itself as the old protocol might not be supported, but SMB/CIFS still is and that's why \hostname for filesharing and such still works.

As for how to resolve a name, I was able to do this:

System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("hostname")

I'm on a domain so it may be simply appending a DNS suffix and doing a DNS lookup, but it worked for me. Give it a try. :)